# Отслеживание клавиатуры на python

Tags: python, winapi, hook

Написал прогу,

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    data = '\n\tKeyboard key :' + str(event.Key)
    t = t + data

    f = open('Logfile.txt', 'a')
    f.write(t)
    f.close()
    t = ''

    return True
```

И вот это

```
hook = pyHook.HookManager()
hook.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hook.HookKeyboard()
```

Все нормально работает, ровно до тех пор, пока не включается русская раскладка клавиатуры. Когда же это происходит прога вылетает, Также это происходит при нажатии на системные клавиши аля Del(shift и alt работают нормально)

Как это пофиксить?

P.S. Как хотя бы сделать так, чтоб прога не падала, все, что введено на русском не сильно интересует

Comment: Прога должна вылетать с каким-нибудь текстом ошибки в консоли

Comment: @andreymal Весь прикол в том, что пока я запускаю через консоль файл .py все нормально, а вот как только скомпилировал в exe , то начинаются проблемы, Винда выдает тольrj неизвестная ошибка, процесс остановлен

Comment: @andreymal А нет, пардонте `TypeError: KeyboardSwitch() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'msg', 'vk_code', 'scan_code', 'ascii', 'flags', 'time', 'hwnd', and 'win_name'`

Comment: @Юрий, лучше не задавать новый вопрос, а дополнять имеющийся (под вопросом для этого есть кнопка "править"). В данном случае этот в вопрос лучше удалить, а новый (более полный) оставить.